# Edit the GlyphView that paints JLabel text in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I would like to edit the `GlyphView` class in charge of painting the text of a `JLabel`. The issue is that I don't see how I can replace the `GlyphView` by, let's say `MyGlyphView`.

Right now, I would like to remove this section:

```
public class GlyphView extends View implements TabableView, Cloneable {
    ...

    public void paint(Graphics g, Shape a) {
        ...

        if (c != null && ! c.isEnabled()) {
            fg = (c instanceof JTextComponent ?
                ((JTextComponent)c).getDisabledTextColor() :
                UIManager.getColor("textInactiveText"));
        }
```

I want the `JLabel` to keep its color when disabled. But more generally, I would like to be able to edit the way text is represented in some of my `JLabel`.

For `JTextPane`, it is very easy to do so as you can set your own `ViewFactory`. But for `JLabel`, I couldn't understand how the views where generated and how to replace them by my own.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think it can be done.  Obviously, there are workarounds;  for instance, JLabels behave mostly the same whether enabled or disabled, so you could just avoid disabling them.  What other rendering do you want to change?

Comment: Actually, right now, I can only think of that one, but I'd like to be able to have a better control over the view of my components. Otherwise, what is the point in separating the model from the view ? But yes, right now I am just overriding the `isEnabled()` method to always return `true`

Comment: You say that you don't think that it can be done. Why is that ? Do you understand the way the view is generated ? Could you point me out how it's done, and maybe why I can't interfere ? Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: The ViewFactory is buried in the look-and-feels.  I’m honestly not sure which class creates it.  What I would do instead is create a JTextPane, and set its foreground, background and font from the Label.\* UIDefaults entries, and give it a null border, so it resembles a JLabel.

Comment: Actually, contrary to what I expected, writing `UIManager.put("textInactiveText", disabledColor);` in a class that extends JLabel didn't make it effective on all the UI but only on the JLabels from that class. So maybe this is the way to go ?

Comment: That affects *all* subsequently created JLabels, so I advise against doing it.  If you must do that, do it at the start of your program, before any JLabels are created.

Comment: That is strange... Anyway, from what I can see, setting the "textInactiveText" did exactly what I needed. Only my class was affected and the other JLabel were not... Maybe is it because that very JLabel is inserted inside a JTextPane... Thanks for discussing this with me.